# Using {@link classname} for external API in my class

Tags: java, classpath, javadoc

I have the following:

```
package test.tester;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class tester {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(tester.class);

    /**
     * {@link org.apache.log4j.Logger}
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        logger.info("test");
    }
}
```

This is generating the links to the `Logger` class successfully, but the javadoc tooling complains like so:

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
tester.java:3: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                      ^

tester.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class test.tester.tester
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(tester.class);
                    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should add the log4j library to Javadoc classpath when running it. Otherwise it can't know what it is.