# Let the @link to a Class of an external library working with JavaDoc under NetBeans

Tags: javadoc, netbeans-7

I have a **Maven** project in **NetBeans 7.3**. I'm preparing the **JavaDoc** for the library. I need to put a link to a class of one of the external library that I imported through the POM file.
E.g.:

```
@see {@link com.google.common.io.Files}
```

The problem is that the link is not created. In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457840/using-link-classname-for-external-api-in-my-class) the author stated that the external library must be added to JavaDoc classpath when running it.

**How can I add the external library to the JavaDoc classpath in NetBeans7.3?**

Comment: This returns `com.google.common.io.Files}` on my NetBeans! I think that the code is wrong! You should simply use `@see com.google.common.io.Files`

Comment: Ok! But this doesn't create any link to the docs related to Files.